# swift cgsize error Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift

//Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads line 12

```
    //Ground
```

`var groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ground")

    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
    sprite.setScale(2.0)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2.0, y: sprite.size.height/2.0)
    self.addChild(sprite)

    var ground = SKNode()
    let size = CGSize.zero
    ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: groundTexture.size().height)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(self.frame.size.width, groundTexture.size().height * 2.0))

    ground.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    self.addChild(ground) <code>`

Comment: What line is number 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Apple's documentation the init method for `CGSize` looks like this: `init(width: Int, height: Int)`. You can read about that here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize/1456247-init

So what you need to do is change this line:

```
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(self.frame.size.width, groundTexture.size().height * 2.0))
```

to this:

```
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: groundTexture.size().height * 2.0))
```